# Getting "cannot find symbol" error in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stock, cannot-find-symbol

I am writing some code to read static stock numbers from a text pad. I ran it to see what was wrong and I cannot seem to fix this cannot find symbol error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StockMarket
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            checkValidity();
        }

        inputFile.close();

    }

    public static boolean checkValidity()
    {

    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    double numberOfShares = inputFile.nextDouble();
    double buyPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
    double buyComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
    double sellPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
    double sellComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got few issues with your `checkValidity()` method as explained below:

(1) Your **`Scanner` object scope exists only inside `main` method**, so pass that object to `checkValidity` method

(2) Validate the inputs inside `checkValidity` method

(3) Your **`checkValidity` method has got `return` type of `boolean`, so you need to `return` a `boolean` value** from it i.e., if validation is successful, return `true` or if validation fails, return `false`

You refer the below code with inline comments:

```
public static boolean checkValidity(Scanner inputFile) {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        double numberOfShares = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double buyPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double buyComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double sellPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double sellComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
        boolean validationSuccess = false;
        //validate your inputs
        // If validations are successful  then set validationSuccess = true;
        return validationSuccess;//return boolean
    }
```

Also, pass the `scanner` object from `main()` as shown below:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
     checkValidity(inputFile);//pass scanner object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `checkValidity` cannot work. You try to access to variable `inputFile` which is not known in the method. You have to pass is as parameter.

```
public static boolean checkValidity(Scanner inputFile)

{

String line = inputFile.nextLine();
double numberOfShares = inputFile.nextDouble();
double buyPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
double buyComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
double sellPricePerShare = inputFile.nextDouble();
double sellComissionRate = inputFile.nextDouble();

}
```